# Changing the brightness on my homepage slider through squarespace

Tags: css, slider, opacity, squarespace

Hey guys I am trying to change the brightness on the background video of my slider. The CMS is squarespace and here is the code

```html
<div class="sqs-video-background content-fill" data-config-url="https://youtu.be/w3W-VLSLT4E" data-config-playback-speed="1" data-config-filter="3" data-config-filter-strength="50" style="overflow: hidden; filter: brightness(0.55);">
```

As you can see the "Brightness at 0.55 is what I need to change im just not sure where to inject the code nor the proper way to write it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use filter property brightness

```
filter:brightness(value);
```

This is example for a image.

```css
img{
  filter:brightness(80%);
  max-width:100%;
  height:auto;
}
img:hover{
  filter: brightness(150%);
 }
```

```html
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/6e/a9/07/6ea907beb0b63463b800c8dd00d48603.jpg">
```

Comment: Thats not gonna work. Here is the site you will see the slider VIDEO in the background I just need to adjust the brightness so you can actually see the video. https://www.bcacunderground.com/

Comment: ```.sqs-video-background .background-video.ready, .sqs-video-background .default-fallback-image.ready, .sqs-video-background .background-video.loaded, .sqs-video-background .default-fallback-image.loaded {
    opacity: 1;
    filter: brightness(51%);
}```

Comment: I changed the video brightness : https://i.stack.imgur.com/eBHRn.png